# Couldn't debug c++ code of NDK using GDB and Eclipse (OS - Windows 7)

Tags: android, c++, eclipse, android-ndk, ndk-gdb

When I'm trying to debug hello-neon example app. But when press F11 (debug) I see the error below (but the app launches and works):

> warning: while parsing target description (at line 1): Target
>   description specified unknown architecture "i386" warning: Could not
>   load XML target description; ignoring Could not AssignProcessToObject

Comment:
I'm using Item Atom Phone.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

neon is an example to demonstrate the neon instruction set from ARM. Since you are running this on an Intel Atom phone, you are seeing this error. Switch to an ARm device or create an AVD running ARM image. If you would like to learn how to use the debugger on Intel platforms please use any other example that comes with Android NDK other than hello-neon and also see this answer for how to debug on NDK
[How to debug C++ code on Android by using Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15347994/how-to-debug-c-code-on-android-by-using-eclipse)